# Why doesn't this typecheck?

Tags: haskell, impredicativetypes

This is toy-example.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes #-}

import Control.Arrow

data From = From (forall a. Arrow a => a Int Char -> a [Int] String)

data Fine = Fine (forall a. Arrow a => a Int Char -> a () String)

data Broken = Broken (Maybe (forall a. Arrow a => a Int Char -> a () String))

fine :: From -> Fine
fine (From f) = Fine g
  where g :: forall a. Arrow a => a Int Char -> a () String
        g x = f x <<< arr (const [1..5])

broken :: From -> Broken
broken (From f) = Broken (Just g) -- line 17
  where g :: forall a. Arrow a => a Int Char -> a () String
        g x = f x <<< arr (const [1..5])
```

And this is what ghci thinks of it:

```
GHCi, version 7.0.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :l toy-example.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( toy-example.hs, interpreted )

toy-example.hs:17:32:
    Couldn't match expected type `forall (a :: * -> * -> *).
                                  Arrow a =>
                                  a Int Char -> a () String'
                with actual type `a0 Int Char -> a0 () String'
    In the first argument of `Just', namely `g'
    In the first argument of `Broken', namely `(Just g)'
    In the expression: Broken (Just g)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Why does `fine` typecheck while `broken` does not?

How do I get `broken` to typecheck?

(In my real code I can add the type parameter `a` to `Broken` if I have to, instead of having it universally quantified inside the constructor, but I'd like to avoid this if possible.)

---

**Edit:** If I change the definition of `Broken` to

```
data Broken = Broken (forall a. Arrow a => Maybe (a Int Char -> a () String))
```

then `broken` typechecks. Yay!

But if I then add the following function

```
munge :: Broken -> String
munge (Broken Nothing) = "something"  -- line 23
munge (Broken (Just f)) = f chr ()
```

then I get the error message

```
toy-example.hs:23:15:
    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
      (Arrow a0) arising from a pattern
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the pattern: Nothing
    In the pattern: Broken Nothing
    In an equation for `munge': munge (Broken Nothing) = "something"
```

How do I get `munge` to typecheck as well?

**2nd edit:** In my real program I have replaced the `Broken (Maybe ...)` constructor with `BrokenNothing` and `BrokenJust ...` constructors (there were already other constructors), but I'm curious how pattern matching is supposed to work in this situation.

Comment: Moving the forall allows outwards one level allows this one to work: `data Broken = Broken (forall a. Arrow a => Maybe (a Int Char -> a () String))`. I suspect section 7.8 of the GHC manual tells you why your version doesn't work, the precise desugaring of forall's is not something I have any expertise on.

Comment: That fixes that problem, but then I can't pattern match against `Nothing` any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImpredicativeTypes` leaves you on quite shaky ground that changes from GHC version to version in any case - they're struggling to find a formulation of impredicativity that appropriately balances power, ease of use and ease of implementation.

In this particular case, trying to put a quantified type inside a `Maybe`, which is a datatype not explicitly defined to behave this way, is really tricky, so I'd advise going for the custom-defined constructors instead as you mention.

I *think* that you can fix `munge` above by re-deconstructing the argument to `Broken` on the RHS, at a time when the type its being used as will be known, e.g.:

```
munge (Broken x@(Just _)) = fromJust x chr ()
```

It's pretty ugly, though.